# lp -o sides=two-sided-long-edge 1.pdf not working

Tags: printing, lp

Any reason why

```
lp -o sides=two-sided-long-edge 1.pdf
```

would only print one-sided ?

I am expecting to see one page printed on both sides, instead I am getting two sheets of paper printed on one side.

when i do

```
lpoptions -p Brother_HL_2270DW_series -l
```

I get

```
PageSize/Media Size: A4 *Letter Legal Executive A5 A5Rotated A6 ISOB5 ISOB6 Env10 EnvDL EnvC5 EnvMonarch 3x5 FanFoldGermanLegal EnvPRC5Rotated B5 Postcard EnvYou4 EnvChou3 Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT
Duplex/Two-Sided Printing: DuplexTumble *DuplexNoTumble None
BRMediaType/Media Type: *Plain Thin Thick ThickPaper2 BOND Env EnvThick EnvThin Recycled Label PostCard
BRInputSlot/Paper Source: *AutoSelect Tray1 Manual
BRResolution/Resolution: 300dpi *600dpi 2400x600dpi
BRHalfTonePattern/Graphics Quality: *Brother Brother4
TonerSaveMode/Toner Save Mode: *OFF ON
BRImproveOutput/Improvement Settings: *OFF BRLessPaperCurl BRFixIntensity
BRSleepTime/Sleep Time: *Default Custom.INTEGER
BRSkipBlank/Skip Blank Page: *OFF ON
BRReduceGhost/Reduce Ghosting: *OFF ON
```

Comment: I had this problem and I fixed it using using -o BRDuplex=DuplexTumble on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know "why", but I fixed my issue by setting the resolution to 612 x 792 - and now the lp command to print double sided works.

Comment: Where do you set that? Looking at Resolution, I typically see 300DPI and 600DPI